# How can I embed \lvert and \rvert into the numerator ?

Tags: math-mode, fractions

How can I embed `\lvert` and `\rvert` into the numerator?

```
$1 - \frac{ \lvert 1 - t_2 \rvert}{y}$
```

The above line gives *Undefined control sequence* error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

is missing.

Answer (score 7):

Herbert's answer is sufficient, but I would like to suggest `\usepackage{mathtools}` as well (it automatically loads amsmath), and then

```
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}
```

The fraction can then be written as `\frac{ \abs{1-t_2} }{y}`.

Using `\abs` gives a number of advantages:

- The code is easier to read (at least, I think so), because one recognizes "absolute value".
- Scaling only needs to be done in one place, namely the optional argument of \abs:

Compare

```
\abs[\Big]{ \int_a^b f(x) }
```

with

```
\Bigl \lvert \int_a^b f(x) \Bigr\rvert
```

- (there is also an `\abs*` version, which is equivalent to prepending `\left` and `\right` to `\lvert` and `\rvert`, but I think this has a tendency to produce too large delimiters; I prefer to find an appropriate size by hand)
- It is impossible to forget the closing delimiter, since it will produce a missing right brace error.

The mathtools package also provides lots of other nice features.